# Change the size of multiple selected polygons as a post-extrude operation

Tags: modeling, workflow

Is there a way to change the size of evenly extruded polygons AFTER performing Extrude/Inset?

It can be very helpful in modeling to be able to work with sets of geometry and yet retain control over the individual elements as if they were being worked on one at a time.

I have tried to use various Pivot settings in combination with Scale but do not have the control over sets of selected faces that will allow me to shape the model the way I'd like to do for mechanical/architectural models.

Step 1: Inset several faces.  This works fine.

[image]

Given that the four interior faces are selected; 
How can I re-size them in relation to one another without them scaling towards each other with a bias they normally would not have if I were working on them individually?

Step 2: Batch Scale the selected Faces.  Now everything is disproportional.

[image]

I have tried changing the Pivot for the Scaling operation but could not get the symmetrical results I was hoping to acheive.

Comment: Please make sure you search Blender SE before asking a question to see if it has already been answered.

Comment: I was going to ask about scaling, but "extrude" got in mind.

Comment: I made an update.

Comment: Can you not scale them each individually by a certain amount?

Comment: @G.Rassovsky For example, in case with a windows. It is much more efficient to scale them together insteed of 1 by 1.

Comment: Try using things like *individual inset* `I I`, or setting the pivot point to *Individual origins* and scaling normally.

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, but they will scale according to the pivot point and when you do them all in one go, you might not get the desired effect.

Comment: @G.Rassovsky I think Vladimir is asking how to get the desired effect all in one go. Also, you can set the pivot point to *individual* to get separate pivot points for each separate selection.

Comment: Are you asking if you can get the inset border the same width all the way around?

Comment: @Gandalf3 Yes, instead of scaling the faces 1 by 1, to be able to scale them together individually, but the face loops around each of the faces to be an equal size (the first image above explains it). I experimented with the pivot point to scale them individually,  but the scaling operation around the center of the selection.

Comment: @Vladimir Sounds like individual inset is what you want. Select all the faces and press `I` twice.

Comment: @Gandalf That's what I want, thanks. But, is there a way just to re-size them? I could make new insets but then I'll have to delete edge loops and having a lot of insets just makes things worse if new edge loops are created just for the sake of adjusting the size.

Comment: @Vladimir Try *Edge slide* (`G G`). Note that starting cursor position plays a big roll in how the operator behaves..

Comment: @Gandalf3 Thanks. It works well. It scales them all evenly, but very often one group is scaled outwards and other is scaled inwards. Is there a way to get the hang of that somehow?

Comment: @Vladimir Try starting with the mouse to one side of all the faces, as opposed to in the middle somewhere.

Comment: @Gandalf3 Got it. It looks like when the cursor is not facing a side of the mesh, it works very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create something like that initially, use *individual inset* (<kbd>I</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>):

[image]

Once the geometry is created, you can resize it with *Edge slide* (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

Note that the direction edges are slid is defined by what side the cursor is on when the operator is called, so if you want to make all the edges go in the same direction, make sure you have the cursor off to one side when you press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: I understood from the comments, but thanks for the answer.